# "bundler: command not found: unicorn" after adding Procfile as told by Heroku Bamboo to Cedar migration guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn, cedar, procfile

As told by the Bamboo to Cedar migration guide, I added this `Procfile` to my Heroku app:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -E $RACK_ENV -c config/unicorn.rb
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

Then I ran `bundle install` and pushed. Now the server does not start anymore:

```
heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
app[web.1]:     /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
app[web.1]:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.0.19/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
app[web.1]:     /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
app[web.1]:     /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
app[web.1]:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:217:in `start'
app[web.1]: [2014-07-17 04:02:16] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
app[web.1]:     /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
app[web.1]:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.0.19/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
app[web.1]: [2014-07-17 04:02:16] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
app[web.1]:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.0.19/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
app[web.1]: [2014-07-17 04:02:16] INFO  going to shutdown ...
app[web.1]: Exiting
app[web.1]:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
app[web.1]:     script/rails:6:in `require'
app[web.1]:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.0.19/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:     script/rails:6:in `<main>'
app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: unicorn
app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add unicorn to your Gemfile and commit both the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock after running `bundle install`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `gem 'unicorn'` to your Gemfile, run `bundle install`.  Commit the updated Gemfile and Gemfile.lock files and push it to Heroku.